# Parse JS add user with role

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to basically have a sign up form that will sign up a user and also add that user that just signed up to a certan role. I got the app signing up the user fine but it isnt creating the role and adding the user to that role. Here is what I had

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Parse.initialize("key", "key");

    //set the user
    var user = new Parse.User();

    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {

      //get the input data
      var username = $('#username').val();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var password = $('#password').val();
      var facility = $('#facility').val();

      //Set the user info
      user.set("facility", "" + facility + "");
      user.set("username", "" + username + "");
      user.set("email", "" + email + "");
      user.set("password", "" + password + "");

      //Sign them up
      user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
          // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
          //Make the role
          var roleACL = new Parse.ACL();
          roleACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
          var role = new Parse.Role("Pro", roleACL);
          role.getUsers().add(username);
          role.save();

          //Show and Hide the alert
          $('#successModal').modal('show');

          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#successModal').modal('hide')
          }, 4000);

          //Clear the form
          $( 'form' ).each(function(){
              this.reset();
          });

       },
        error: function(user, error) {
          // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }

      });

      return false

    });

</script>
```

My thought was create the user then on successful user creation create the role and add the user to that role. Seems not to be working though.

[image: backend] [image: error]

Answer (score 3):

code the querys a user

```
 querys a role

 then adds the user to the role

 var qu = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var qr = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
  qr.get(roleId, {
  success: function(role) {
      _role = role;
      qu.get(userId, {
        success: function(user) {
            _role.getACL().setRoleReadAccess(_role, true);
            _role.getUsers().add(user);
            _role.save();
            response.success(_role.toJSON());
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            console.log('got role, failed on get user');
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

The aim is to add the newly saved user to an existing role, so that role must be queried, not created when the user is saved.

Since you must the save of a user, query a role, and save that role -- three asynch operations that must be performed in sequence -- it's advisable to use promises, lest the code become unreadably indented, so...

```
// prepare the user as you have it, then
user.signUp().then(function(user) {
    // query the role, you can get it with the role name
    var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    roleQuery.equalTo("name", "Pro");
    return roleQuery.first();
}).then(function(role) {
    role.getUsers().add(user);
    return role.save();
}).then(function() {
    // no need to set a timer. with the promise, we know exactly when we are done
    $('#successModal').modal('hide');
}, function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
});
```

Be sure to first create the "Pro" role manually using the data browser.  Read through [the security section in the programming guide.](https://parse.com/docs/data#security)

Also note, if this happens for every user, the role code is a good candidate to be part of an `afterSave` cloud function on PFUser.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the process you are going through here but when I did this I got a `Error: 101 object not found for update` . The I created the role and this code actually does sign up the user but I get that error, a js `POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_Role/IwVmnoPJHx 404 (Not Found)`  and the user is not connected to the role in Core .

Comment: So you can see a role named "Pro" in the _Role table in your data browser?  That should be found by the simple query by the name column.  And is "IwVmnoPJHx" the id of that role object?  Could you paste a picture of it in the data browser, maybe there's a clue there.

Comment: I added some images to the main question

Comment: Seems to be working now I think. I had to change the permission to Write as well.